# Where to get the WEB-INF folder for a site present outside of cfusion/wwwroot?

Tags: iis, iis-7, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have just put all my project files in E:\testproj and created a new site IIS pointing to this folder.

I have also changed the host file also accordingly. But in the default cfusion/wwwroot folder there is folder called WEB-INF.

But in my project folder there is no WEB-INF folder. I need some modification on WEB-INF/web.xml .

Shall I add it as a virtual directory to my site or is there any other way?

Comment: Why you need to add some settigs under WEB-INF.
Are you facing any mapping issue ?
To run your site just point your Project directory location in IIS and do necessary host changes, thats it.
Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Yo don't need any mapping separately. You can create a virtual directory pointing to E:\testproj.

Comment: @AnitKumar: Everything is working fine now. Only thing is I need to add some filter-mapping to web.xml to stop clickjacking attack.So if I will add it it `cfusion/wwwroot/web-inf/web.xml` will it work for my site i.e testproj?

Comment: You can use 
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CFClickJackFilterDeny</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/testClick/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
and refer to http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/security-improvements.html for more info

Comment: @AnitKumar: Yes I know. But I just want to know in which web.xml file,as my project does not reside inside wwwroot, and if i will modify web.xml inside cfusion/wwwroot/web-inf, will it work?